# how to produce data for filtering (specifically ekf and ukf)? -or- can you supply me with data?

Tags: data-analysis

I am currently implementing Kalman filters (I have EKF and UKF) and need some data to test my codes in matlab. I have a set of samples I used, but I need more. How do i produce more data? Say I wrote:
$$ t=1:0.001:22 $$
as time samplings, with $dt=0.001$. Now say I have a 3 dimension state and I want the real trajectory (what i try to follow/estimate) to be $$ [cos(t); 2t; 1-sin^2(t)]$$
how do i produce the velocities, accelerations, and other measurements to these model?

note: this is supposed to be traking the rotation of a body around its axis (i.e., the trajectory im following is the values of angles). what i need is the angular velocities, the angular accelerations and the magnetic field on the body (those are the measurement i want to use in the measurement update stage), and i have a function that supposed to give me the relation between a current state and all those other things.

if you can explain to me how to do this, or just give me data to test my ukf with, i will be very greatful.

thanks, Joseph

Comment: What is your measurement process/model?

Comment: im not sure how to write here, but in here you can find the model: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1794616/does-the-ukf-work-or-how-would-a-correct-implementation-of-ukf-look-like (this is another question i asked, and contains the model)

Comment: You take the true state at t and compute the expected measurement corresponding to the state and contaminate it with the measurement noise thus producing simulated measurements at each time of interest.